# Combine two tables of contents?

Tags: python, bash

I would like to combine two tables of contents into one.
In the first given table, there is a  page number at the end of each chapter/section title. In the second given table, there is no page number at each chapter/section title, but there are section titles of another lower level.
The desired output is a table by adding the chapter/section titles of the lower level in the second table to the first table, so that the output table has all the information from the two given tables.

I wonder how to do that in bash, or Python? Thanks.

An example, given

```
Chapter 1. The  Big  Picture 7
1.1  Levels  and  Layers  of  Abstraction  in  a  Linux  System 8
1.2  Hardware:  Understanding  Main  Memory 9
1.3  The  Kernel 10
1.4  User  Space 12
Chapter 2. Basic  Commands  and  Directory  Hierarchy 14
2.1  The  Bourne  Shell:  /bin/sh 15
2.2  Using  the  Shell 15
2.3  Basic  Commands 17
```

and

```
1. The Big Picture

    1.1 Levels and Layers of Abstraction in a Linux System
    1.2 Hardware: Understanding Main Memory
    1.3 The Kernel
        1.3.1 Process Management
        1.3.2 Memory Management
        1.3.3 Device Drivers and Management
        1.3.4 System Calls and Support
    1.4 User Space

2. Basic Commands and Directory Hierarchy

    2.1 The Bourne Shell: /bin/sh
    2.2 Using the Shell
        2.2.1 The Shell Window
        2.2.2 cat
        2.2.3 Standard Input and Standard Output
    2.3 Basic Commands
```

The desire output is

```
1. The Big Picture 7

    1.1 Levels and Layers of Abstraction in a Linux System 8
    1.2 Hardware: Understanding Main Memory 9
    1.3 The Kernel 10
        1.3.1 Process Management
        1.3.2 Memory Management
        1.3.3 Device Drivers and Management
        1.3.4 System Calls and Support
    1.4 User Space 12

2. Basic Commands and Directory Hierarchy 14

    2.1 The Bourne Shell: /bin/sh 15
    2.2 Using the Shell 15
        2.2.1 The Shell Window
        2.2.2 cat
        2.2.3 Standard Input and Standard Output
    2.3 Basic Commands 17
```

Note that the leading white spaces of each line don't matter.

Comment: The desired output and the second part table are the same.

Comment: The output has page numbers for those titles appearing also in the first table.

Comment: Is it only about page numbers?

Comment: This seems very straightforward in Python, anyway: read the first file and build a dictionary mapping section numbers to page numbers; then read the second file line by line, and if the section number is found, add the corresponding page number before the end of the line.  What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, here is an `awk` and a python solution.

### Using `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{p[($1=="Chapter")?$2:$1]=$NF;next} {print $0,p[$1]}' file1 file2
1. The Big Picture 7

    1.1 Levels and Layers of Abstraction in a Linux System 8
    1.2 Hardware: Understanding Main Memory 9
    1.3 The Kernel 10
        1.3.1 Process Management 
        1.3.2 Memory Management 
        1.3.3 Device Drivers and Management 
        1.3.4 System Calls and Support 
    1.4 User Space 12

2. Basic Commands and Directory Hierarchy 14

    2.1 The Bourne Shell: /bin/sh 15
    2.2 Using the Shell 15
        2.2.1 The Shell Window 
        2.2.2 cat 
        2.2.3 Standard Input and Standard Output 
    2.3 Basic Commands 17
```

#### How it works

`awk` reads input one record (line) at a time and each record is divided into fields.  FNR is the total number of lines read so far from the current file and NR is the total number of lines read so far from all files.  With that in mind, let's examine each `awk` command in turn:

- `NR==FNR{p[($1=="Chapter")?$2:$1]=$NF;next}`

  When `NR==FNR`, that means that we are working on the first file `file1`, the one with the page numbers.  We save the page numbers in an array `p` with the keys being the section number.

  The page number is always the last field which, in `awk`, is denoted as `$NF`.

  A slight complication is that the section is the first field, denoted `$1`, on most lines but the second field on chapter lines.  Thus, if the line starts with `Chapter`,  that is if `$1=="Chapter"`, then we use `$2` as the key.  Otherwise `$1` is used.  This is all done with the slightly cryptic ternary statement:

  p[($1=="Chapter")?$2:$1]=$NF

  The `next` command tells `awk` to skip the rest of the commands and start over on the next line.
- `{print $0,p[$1]}`

  If we get to this command, that means that we are now working on the second file, `file2`.  In this case, all we have to to is print the whole line, `$0`, followed by the page number if any `p[$1]`.

### Using Python

The logic here is almost identical to the `awk` version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
p = {}
with open('file1') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        p[words[1] if words[0] == 'Chapter' else words[0]] = words[-1]

with open('file2') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line:
            num = line.split()[0]
            line += " " + p.get(num, '')
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that that the chapters are the same data in the same order (no need for matching):

```
# open both files, plus an output file, then...

for line in file1.readlines():
    # gets you a sequence of page numbers
    page_nums.append(line.split()[-1])

for i, line in ennumerate(file2.readlines()):
    if line != '\n':
        output += ' {}\n'.format(page_nums[i]))
    else:
        output += line

# then write output back down
```